# how to map collection in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want return data if a < b then a = b, if using foreach i have to make empty array first and parsing data to te empty array, how if record i much, that take time

```
public function getDepreciation(){
        $values = $this->repository->getDepreciation();
        $data = [];
        foreach($values as $value){
            if($value->depresiation_per_month > $value->balance_value){
                $value->depresiation_per_month = $value->balance_value;
            }
            array_push($data,$value->depresiation_per_month,$value->balance_value);
        }
        return $data;
    }
is there is simple code than my above, since i have to make relist many array
```

Comment: oh it is working,thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert this array in a Collection then handle it easier by using the transform method.
First you have to create the collection using your array [Create Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#creating-collections)

```
$values = collect($values);
```

Then you can iterate over the collection using the transform method and apply your logic [Transform Method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-transform)

Finally you have to convert your collection into an array using the toArray method [toArray Method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-toarray)

I hope this works for you